# SVG or SVGZ, what should I use?

Tags: svg, file-format, compression

I tried compressed plain SVG (.svgz), the files are smaller and it looks the same than the regular .svg. Is there any downside? Can I use always .svgz?

Comment: this isn't really a design question. It's a browser support question. Use SVGZ if the browsers you are targeting support it.

Answer (score 2):

.svgz are simply gzipped svg files. The only caveat in their use is that the web-server delivering them has gzip enabled and is able to correctly set gzip headers.

All (well IE8+!) browsers support the format itself

We're venturing into stackoverflow territory here, but enabling gzip on your server is likely as easy as pasting this into .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
 mod_gzip_on Yes
 mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
 mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
 mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
 mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
 mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

PS - Also check out [SVG scrubber](http://www.codedread.com/scour/) which is very cool.